# How to print lines in Python

Tags: python, ruby

I've come across lines like this in Python:

```
print "Let's talk about %s." % my_name
```

However, I've seen cases in Ruby where these two have equivalent output:

`print "Let's talk about #{my_name}."`

`print "Let's talk about %s." % my_name"`

Is there only one way to print the same line in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python there are also several ways:

```
print "let's talk about this %s" % my_name
print "let's talk about this {:s}".format(my_name)
print "let's talk about this", my_name
```

all generate the same output. However, use of the [.format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting) method (available since Python v 2.6) is encouraged over the old-style `%` (To quote from the [What's New in 3.0](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html): "*...the % operator is still supported; it will be deprecated in Python 3.1 and removed from the language at some later time.*")

Lastly, as of Python v3.x `print` is a function, so all print statements require `()`.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby, the part between the `{}` is an expression. Python has no way to evaluate expressions *inside* the format string this way.

```
print "Let's talk about #{my_name}."
```

In the simple case where the expression in just a variable, you can use

```
print "Let's talk about %(my_name)s"%{'my_name':my_name}
```

or any of the bunch of other alternatives given in other answers here.

The preferred way is to use format(). eg.

```
print "Let's talk about {my_name}".format(my_name=my_name)
```

Comment: I just started to use the .format method .. why would the last print you show be the preferred way? I find it incredibly verbose. I'm not trying to argue, but I don't see the benefit. Perhaps it's just the context of this simple example? Or is there a good reason for this?

Comment: @Levon, format() gives you a lot of control over the output - spacing, padding, etc. Using a mapping for substitutions in text output is a good habit, because it makes life much easier if you ever have to do i18n

Answer (score 0):

You could also concatenate strings. This is less pythonic and gives you less control over the final appearance of your output, but some non-programmers seem to find this easier to read (like if you're discussing a specific calculation):

```
print "Let's talk about " + str( my_name )
```

The str() function may or may not be necessary, but it allows you to add in other datatypes (like integers) without getting a TypeError.

For more information on string.format() vs %, see this older post:
[Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers here, there are also mapping keys, which I took way too long to discover in my life with Python.

```
>>> '%(foo)s' % {'foo': 'bar'}
'bar'
```

Have a look at [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) for the whole shebang.

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorites is to use a dictionary for values:

```
>>> values = {"name": "john"}
>>> print "Let's talk about {name}".format(**values)
Let's talk about john
```

Comment: Depends on the extent of the data you need to output via print.  For a single line, with a single value it's overkill, but when you start to increase the variables in the output it can be much cleaner.